# Using 'as simple as I can' correctly

Tags: grammaticality

I have to present a medical case, and I feel a little odd about the sentence below:

> Because of her prolong stay and multi-organ involvement, I will present this case as simple as I can.

I feel like using 'as simple as I can' is wrong. Should I use 'could'?

Comment: You should specify -- which word do you think you are not using correctly?

Comment: I feel like using ' as simple as I can' is wrong. Should I use could?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used present tense prolong, but for your sentence to make sense it should be past tense:

> "Because of her **prolonged** stay and multi-organ involvement, I will
>   present this case as simple as I can".

*multi-organ involvement*, does sound quite odd.

Perhaps multi-organ complications , would sound more natural and the word complications is often used in the medical context.

> "Because of her prolonged stay and multi-organ **complications**, I will
>   present this case as simple as I can".

You then need to use the adverb simply in place of the adjective simple.

***[Simply](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simply)*** (Cambridge)

> He explained it as simply as he could, but the class still didn't
>   understand.

So we now arrive at this:

> "Because of her prolonged stay and multi-organ complications, I will
>   present this case as **simply** as I can".

I think perhaps you actually mean to say this however:

> "Because of her prolonged stay and multi-organ complications, I will
>   present this case as **expeditiously** as I can".

***[Expeditiously](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expeditiously)*** (Farlex)

> Acting or done with speed and efficiency.

Because if I read your meaning correctly, the patient has already had a prolonged stay and the case has been complicated, so you want to present the case with speed and efficiency to move things forward.

So we arrive at this:

> "Because of her prolonged stay and multi-organ complications, I will
>   present this case as expeditiously as I can".

Which I think is a fair reflection of what I understand you wanted to say, and is also grammatical.

Unless of course you did mean to say you are presenting the case in simple terms, in which case the earlier construction we arrived at would work just fine:

> "Because of her prolonged stay and multi-organ complications, I will
>   present this case as simply as I can".

Comment: You're very welcome! Pleased it was useful.